# PHP file not parsed when accessed outside vm

Tags: php, apache2, debian, virtual-machine

I have a strange issue with parsing of php files.
I'm running a pretty standard development environment with virtual machine running apache2 and server root set to my shared folder. Let's say I have an indes.php file containing simple line of code
`<?php echo 'test' ?>`

When I run it directly through php in VM's console, it parses properly returning string 'test', but when accessing it via browser on my host machine it displays just plain file contents. Any html located in the file is also not parsed and displayed as-is.

Comment: Sounds like your php server isn't running. Try a     sudo apachectl restart on your host machine

Comment: Is your Apache server configured to run PHP? Check the httpd.conf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by installing `libapache2-mod-php5` and running `a2enmod php5` to enable the module.